# Google Chrome Extension not working in canary 31.0.1605.1 canary aura

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just looked on the [Getting Started: Building a Chrome Extension](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html) Page, and I couldn't get the One-Click Kittens extension to work on my version of canary (31.0.1605.1 canary Aura). If I right click on it and click on "Inspect popup", the extension shows up with a developer window, but it won't work if I just click on it.

It works in Chrome Dev Version 30.0.1568.2, though.

I downloaded all the files from the website.

Is it a problem with the code, Google Chrome canary, or something else?

Thanks.

Comment: Canary is a daily updated developer build. It can contain (serious) bugs. Don't test extensions on that, but test it on the stable version instead.

Comment: ok. i just tested it on canary because i usually use it to see all the new features of chrome